# Exercise of the definition of the limit

Tags: limits

Can you help me with this exercise?

The fuel efficiency E depends on the speed $s$ of the mobile phone. A car travels at $100\%$ fuel efficiency when traveling at $55$ miles per hour ($MPH$). Suppose that the fuel efficiency in percent is given by the following equation, which is a function of the fuel speed $(s)$ in $(MPH)$:

$$E(s)=-0.033058(s^2-110s)$$

If you want the car to travel at least $95\%$ efficient, how close to $55~MPH$ should you drive?

Thanks

Comment: Basically you just have to solve $E(s) \geq 95$. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the quadratic equation to get interval around 55 mph
$$0.033058s^2 - 3.63638s + 95 = 0$$